# spring boot cant connect spring boot to postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, postgresql-10

I am trying to connect Spring Boot back-end to PostgreSQL but get this error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration 
required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty 
(spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: 
org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did 
not find any beans


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 
'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

I have been struggling with this error for 2 days till this moment

I have these dependencies in my pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this is my application.yml

```yaml
spring:
 jpa:
  database: POSTGRESQL
  show-sql: true
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: create-drop
 datasource:
  platform: postgres
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/H4E
  username: postgres
  password: 123456
```

I am using PostgreSQL 10 with pgAdmin 3 LTS

Comment: Try adding a connection pool like Apache DBCP2 as a dependency in your POM, I think it should already come with one in the dependencies of the JPA starter but maybe they changed that.

Comment: whats your springboot version?

Comment: looks like issue with with your package strcture. Can you please share package tree diagram?

Comment: change postgresql JDBC driver version. Try to use `42.2.1` instead of `9.4-1206-jdbc42`.

Comment: also (just in case) append quotes to your DB connection string `url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/H4E"`

Comment: are you sure that your application.yml file is picked up by Spring Boot?

Comment: @naxa how to know if the .yml file is picked up or not ?

Comment: @VinayPrajapati 1.5.10.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `driverClassName` property under the `spring.datasource`. You should get something like this

```
spring:
    jpa:
        database: POSTGRESQL
        show-sql: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: create-drop
    datasource:
        platform: postgres
        url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/H4E"
        username: postgres
        password: 123456
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```